# Will buying a higher output PSU help make my GPU run cooler?

Tags: gpu, power-supply

I have an MSI Radeon HD4350 that tends to get pretty hot.  So hot in fact that I've mounted a fan directly under it.

The computer I've put in in is an AMD 64 X2 5000+ with the stock 250W power supply.  The graphics card specs. says it needs a minimum recommended 300W PSU.

So my question is, if I buy a higher output PSU (460W to be exact) will it help my GPU to run cooler?  Possibly helping it use less strain to maintain it's capacity especially while running games or 3D home design software of which I do both.  Or will the power supply unit not help at all?

**if it helps...**
Windows 7 - 2GB RAM - 3 fans

Comment: I have read the nvidia 8800 gtx can run up to 170 celcius although not recommended.  I have a gtx 275 currently and it will run around 70 to 100 celcius.

Comment: Related: [Is it ok to run a system with a PSU that idles at only 10% of its capacity?](http://superuser.com/questions/303356/is-it-ok-to-run-a-system-with-a-psu-that-idles-at-only-10-of-its-capacity/303401#303401)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could indirectly make your GPU run cooler. If your PSU is major source of heat because it's too weak, obtaining more powerful one will make PSU produce less heat. This way it could reduce system temperature, but if your PSU isn't overloaded, there will not be any major difference and probably no measurable difference.

Just so you know, if the GPU is overtaxing the PSU, PSU will overheat and not GPU. If your PSU can't convert enough power and is of relatively good quality, it will shut down. Really cheap ones may die in such cases.

By the way, for system such as yours, I'd definitely buy better PSU. You'll need at least 300W PSU of good quality of stronger PSU of lower quality (cheap PSUs tend to advertise maximum power output, while good PSUs tend to advertise sustainable power output)

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a "too strong" power supply, the PSU only delivers the energy that your components draw.

The same way, a "too weak" PSU will simply not supply enough power for the computer components to function correctly, which will be immediately evident.

Final answer: The PSU is not to blame for the temperature of the GPU. The problem has more to do with ventilation and/or thermal paste, problems which are better handled by a qualified repairman.

The most you could do yourself is clean well the computer, and especially air intakes.
If it's a laptop, you could set it up at an angle to allow air movement below, or get a cooling pad.

Comment: Actually, there is "too strong" power supply. Power supplies used in computers need to have a minimum load in order to start and their efficiency is function of their load. Power supplies are usually most efficient when they are at about 80% of their load. +1 for cleaning, I think that it will help the most.

Answer (score 1):

The heat is generated by electrical components converting electrical energy to thermal energy as a byproduct of processing.

Wattage is a measure of TOTAL electrical energy.  More electrical energy = more potential for thermal energy conversion.

Higher wattage COULD mean more heat.  It is extremely unlikely it will make your GPU cooler.  How hot is it running, what is the factory installed cooling like?  You may be better off getting an aftermarket heat sink and fan, and/or liquid cooling if it is a major issue for you.